# Using Zenphoto with Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, zenphoto

I want to use zenphoto with my symfony2 website. I would do so by making calls to zenphoto to retrieve images. Here's a non-symfony2 coding example from another one of my sites that it would use as a basis:

```
<?php
define('WEBPATH', 'zenphoto');
require_once(WEBPATH . "/zp-core/template-functions.php");

$currentPage = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$imageNum = 0;
if (isset($_GET['imageNum'])) 
$imageNum = $_GET['imageNum'];

$gallery = new Gallery();
$numAlbums = $gallery->getNumAlbums();
$gallery->getAlbums();
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $numAlbums; $i++)
{
$album = $gallery->getAlbum($i);
$title = $album->getTitle();
if ($title == "Overview") break;
} 
$album->getImages();
$totalImages = $album->getNumImages() - 1;
$image = $album->getImage($imageNum);
$sizedImage = $image->getSizedImage(600);
?>
```

There's more code buried in the HTML. All the code would end up in a controller. My question is how to best integrate zenphoto if at all. I could just install the code independent of the framework, but I imagine there's a better way.

There's a whole front end for uploading and managing images as well as admin functions. These web pages would be independent of Symfony as it doesn't seem possible to integrate them.

Answer (score 0):

I went with the simple approach of just including the libraries into the controller.

```
define('SERVERPATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/zenphoto");
define('WEBPATH','/zenphoto');
require_once(SERVERPATH.'/zp-core/template-functions.php');
```

The zenphoto directory is at the same level as my symfony directory. This worked find, but when I tried a simple call to the API, it failed in the zenphoto code. When I asked about the problem on the [zenphoto forum](http://www.zenphoto.org/support/topic.php?id=648967), I was told I would have to do a lot of manual set up to make it work. At this point, I gave up and went with placing my images on flickr and using their API.